# How do I add Google Analytics to a Meteor app?

Tags: javascript, meteor, google-analytics

I see that we cannot directly add code to our HTML tag in Meteor, what is a good/canon way of adding Google Analytics to Meteor? I googled it and there are many outdated resources, but the most up to date is a package  called meteor-ganalytics. I'm not sure if it does directly that. Any help?

Answer (score 3):

We've created a package that integrates Google Analytics, Mixpanel, KISSmetrics and other platforms under one API with Meteor.

The package adds the packages and makes them ready-to-use in the Meteor. All you need to do is add the package and and add your trackingIDs/tokens in settings.

[okgrow:analytics](https://atmospherejs.com/okgrow/analytics)

Answer (score 1):

There is a package available `meteor add datariot:ganalytics` that adds GA to Meteor. It allows the user to configure analytics and set GA events.

Found here: https://github.com/datariot/meteor-ganalytics

Answer (score 1):

If you use Iron Router, you may then look at this package:

https://atmospherejs.com/reywood/iron-router-ga

Install it, then add your Google Analytics account ID to `settings.json` file

then add

`Router.configure({
    trackPageView: true
});`

And it will stark tracking your routes. No extra code required.